# How to remove a selected item from a selectOneMenu inside a dataTable?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:dataTable/>` and on each row I have a `<p:selectOneMenu/>` and they are a list of integers from 1 to the number of items present on the list. So if I have a list with 30 items on my `<p:dataTable />` on each `<p:selectOneMenu/>` will show the options from 1 to 30. However, I am facing a problem with these `<p:selectOneMenu />` inside my `<p:dataTable />`. If an item is selected in one row I have to remove this item from the others `<p:selectOneMenu/>`. For instance, if the item '1' is selected then all the others  cannot have the number '1' available as an option to be selected.

So is there a way that I can do on my managed bean/controller? I've tried to get the `<p:selectionOneMenu/>` by using javascript but I didn't succeed because I had problems to get the clientId and also the selectOneMenu uses a div in order to show the items. Any thoughts on this issue?

This is my xhtml

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTableSolicitacoes" value="#{pesquisarItemSolicInvestController.listaSolicitacoes}"
            selectionMode="single" var="_solicitacao" rowKey="#{_solicitacao.index}" rowIndexVar="index"
            selection="#{pesquisarItemSolicInvestController.linhaSelecionada}"
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{pesquisarItemSolicInvestController.onRowSelect}" process="@(#dataTableSolicitacoes)" update="@(#dataTableSolicitacoes), @(#panelBotoes)" />       
        <p:column style="vertical-align: middle; width: 60px !important;">
            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{messages.LABEL_PRIORIDADE}" title="#{messages.TITLE_INFORME_ORDEM_PRIO}"/> 
            </f:facet>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="cbPrioridade" value="#{_solicitacao.prioridade}" style="width:60px !important;"
                styleClass="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
                disabled="#{!mf:hasPermission(securityController,'manterItensEnviados,manter')}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{pesquisarItemSolicInvestController.listaPrioridades}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{pesquisarItemSolicInvestController.mudarPrioridade(_solicitacao.index)}" 
                        process="@(#dataTableSolicitacoes), @(#panelBotoes)" update="@(#dataTableSolicitacoes), @(#panelBotoes)" />                 
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Try the OmniFaces.Ajax function to update a column in the datatable

Comment: Thanks @MarouaneLakhal but I don't have permission to add Omnifaces to my project but it is a great and simple option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have different option arrays for each select one menu in your backing bean.

then use them in f:selectItems as below:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{pesquisarItemSolicInvestController.listaPrioridades[index]}" />
```

in your event listener method, get your row index as a parameter, as below:

```
#{pesquisarItemSolicInvestController.mudarPrioridade(_solicitacao.index, index)}
```

then remove the selected item from all option arrays except `listaPrioridades[index]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tt_dev it helped me a lot. I had to add a valueChangeListener as well in order to get the old value so I could re-add it to the lists.